# Animating with jQuery using swipe

Tags: jquery, animation, swipe

Hi I have a problem moving a div of slides when swiping left and right. I'm using:

```
$("#slidetrack").on("swipeleft",function(){
    $("#slidetrack").animate({
        "margin-left": "-=800px" //go left
 }, {duration: 1600, easing: "easeOutExpo", queue: false});

$("#slidetrack").on("swiperight",function(){
    $("#slidetrack").animate({
        "margin-left": "+=800px" //go right
 }, {duration: 1600, easing: "easeOutExpo", queue: false});
```

This works ok but the problem I have occurs when the user swipes again too quickly. Let's say the user swipes twice in quick succession, the second swipe occurs only 400 pixels into the 800px animation of the first swipe, the total number of pixels the panel track should have moved is 1600 however in this instance it will only have moved 400+800=1200px.

I've tried using is(':animated') to check if the animation is still occurring and therefore prevent another animation:

```
        if ($("#slidetrack").is(':animated')) {

          return false;

        };
```

and this does work to a degree but it isn't suitable as the user may want to swipe quickly through the slides and cannot do so with this method.

So is there a better way?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make it so that the successive swipes will cause the currently running animation to immediately [`.stop()`](https://api.jquery.com/stop/#stop-clearQueue-jumpToEnd) by passing *true* to the two optional arguments: `clearQueue` and `jumpToEnd`.

```js
$('#slidetrack').on('keydown', function (e) {
  var $track = $(this);
  var animating = $track.is(':animated');

  if (animating) {
    // Stops the currently-running animation, 
    // removes queued animation and 
    // completes the animation immediately
    $track.stop(true, true);
  }

  var offset = 200;
  var direction = {
    [$.ui.keyCode.LEFT]: '-=',
    [$.ui.keyCode.RIGHT]: '+=',
  }
  [e.which || e.keyCode];
  
  if (direction) {
    $('#slidetrack').animate({
      'left': `${direction}${offset}px`
    }, {
      duration: 1600,
      easing: "easeOutExpo",
      queue: false,
      step: function (n) {
        $track.text(Math.floor(n) + 'px');
      }
    });
  }
});
```

```css
#slidetrack {
  background-color: lavender;
  width: 55px;
  height: 45px;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<p>Click on the box once, and use LEFT & RIGHT arrow (simulating swipes)</p>
<div id="slidetrack" tabindex="0"></div>
```

Comment: Brilliant, thank you. I just need to convert those key inputs to swipes, but reckon that will do it perfectly.

Comment: great I didn't have to convert it key inputs. All I had to do was add this from you code to the beginning of each swipe function and it worked: var $track = $(this);
  var animating = $track.is(':animated');

  if (animating) {
    // Stops the currently-running animation, 
    // removes queued animation and 
    // completes the animation immediately
    $track.stop(true, true);
  }